# How to store grep results in a buffer in Vim?

Tags: vim

I want to debug a process, hence I attached strace to the process and redirected the output to a file and then performed the operation. During the process it has created a lot of processes. So here is what I want to do, I want to select all the system calls executed by a process. To do that I used grep command with pattern as pid:

```
:grep pid %
```

It shows the result but I am not able to traverse through the result, it promts

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

and returns to the file. What I would like to do is store the result in a buffer and then have a look into it and if required save it into a file or else discard it and return to the original file. Is there a way to do this with out exiting from the vim editor? Thanks in advance.

I would like to search with the result and store that in a buffer.

Comment: Instead `grep` just use `/pattern` and then traverse it forward pressing `N` or backward pressing `shift+N`

Comment: Are you trying to view all of them from within vim? /pid should help you search. Or do you want all those lines into a file?

Comment: /pattern will be helpful to search within a code but here I want all the searched lines gathered in one place.

Comment: @Rahul: or use `:g//p#` to see grep like output for the whole buffer

Comment: if you want to operate on all those lines: `:g/pid/ normal >>` will indent these lines, `:v/pid/d` deletes all other lines;

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can go to older searches, and back easily:

```
:copen
:colder " goes to older
:cnewer " newer
```

You can have another search using `lvimgrep` (uses location window):

```
:lopen
:lnext
etc...
```

It also has history:

```
:lolder
:lnewer
```

You can read into any buffer:

```
:r!grep bla **/*.cs
```

Finally, any command that gives output, can be redirected with the `redir` command:

```
:redir >> file
:grep bla **/*.cs
:redir END
```

See `:he redir` for the many ways to use it (redirect into registers or variables).

Comment: in case of lvimgrep, after one search and lopen, how do I search in this window?

Comment: in :r!grep bla **/*.cs can you explain it a bit more? what does grin means here?

Comment: @hue: sry my html emoticon was confusing there. I meant to /joke/ that obviously the usual commands apply.  ':r!' Reads the console output of any (shell) command

Comment: At your first question: you can use % to represent the current filename; you used that in your own question so I assumed you knew what it meant

Comment: one more thing: using redir you can set the output to a variable as well `:help redir`.  ex: `redir => m | silent registers | redir END` then you can access that result at any time, ex: `put=m`

Answer (score 43):

Over the years of reading all kind of logs, I learned this little trick:

```
:%!grep pattern
```

It simply replaces the current buffer contents with grep output (so to go back to the original logs you have to simply press `u`).

You can also use it with other tools:

```
:%!ack pattern
:%!ag pattern
:%!rg pattern
```

Note that you can also run these commands on other files then the current one. The following 2 commands would replace the current buffer with results of grepping over the current file (second `%` character, which would be redundant for grep in this case) and otherfile.txt respectively:

```
:%!grep pattern %
:%!grep pattern otherfile.txt
```

For me it's the simplest and the best solution for fast grepping of big files in Vim and I'm pretty surprised no one ever mentioned it.

Comment: Really wish I could upvote this more. I've been looking for this for years.

Comment: To understand how the above commands work in vim: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5837

Answer (score 3):

I thought that `:grep` results were stored by default in the `quickfix` window.

Try to use `:copen` after running a grep command. I expect that you'll find your results there.

( :cclose to close the quickfix window)

It is not really a buffer, but as long as you are not starting another search your result list will stay intact.

You can "yank" the content of the quickfix window to a new buffer.

- Go into quickfix with `:copen`
- Yank its content with `yG`
- open a new buffer with `:new`
- Paste the content with `p`
- Save it with `:w Process1.txt`

Repeat and rinse for multiple search/process.

Comment: xavier that was helpful. But yes I would like to start another search.

Comment: @hue : I have added some info on how to save your results. However, it might cumbersome to repeat on multiple process. The correct solution would be to do the same steps with a Vim script function but I am not proficient enough in Vimscript to provide a solution quickly but I am sure that someone else will.

Comment: Try looking at `getqflist()` and `setqflist()`. I know that they exist, though never used them actually.

Answer (score 1):

@romainl 's answer on [how grep results into separate buffer or split window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086306/how-grep-results-into-separate-buffer-or-split-window?noredirect=1&lq=1) gives a much cleaner answer than quickfix/location lists.

```
:vnew | 0r!grep foo #
:tabe | 0r!grep foo #
```

but Quickfix lists are sort of intended for what you are doing but not the way you are doing it; however, it's tedious to set up unless it's a recurrent task.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to store the line numbers of highlighted words along with their corresponding lines in gvim (similar to :g/), we can add the following code to ~/.gvimrc. Then, use :F to open the [Scratch] File.

**command! -nargs=? F let @a='' | execute 'redir @a | silent g//print' | redir END | silent execute 'new | setlocal bt=nofile | put=split(@a, ''\n'') | set syntax=vera | 1d'**

command! -nargs=? F: This defines a custom command named "F" that can take an optional argument (-nargs=? specifies that the command can take zero or more arguments).

- let @a='': This clears the content of register "a". The register "@" is commonly used for yanking and pasting text in Vim.
- execute 'redir @a | silent g//print': This part of the command executes the :global command (g//print) with the provided argument(s). The :global command is used to perform an operation on lines that match a given pattern. In this case, it's searching for lines that match the specified pattern (given by ) and printing them. The redir @a part redirects the output of the command to register "a".
- redir END: This stops the redirection of output, ending the :redir command started previously. It ensures that subsequent output is not redirected.
- silent execute 'new | setlocal bt=nofile | put=split(@a, ''\n'') | set syntax=vera | 1d': This executes a series of commands silently:
  new: This opens a new buffer.
- setlocal bt=nofile: This sets the buffer type (bt) to "nofile", which means it's not associated with any file.
- put=split(@a, '\n'): This splits the content of register "a" into lines and puts it into the buffer. The split() function is used to split a string into a list based on a delimiter ('\n' represents a newline character).
- set syntax=vera: This sets the syntax highlighting of the buffer to "vera".
- 1d: This deletes the first line of the buffer.

So, in summary, the command searches for lines matching a pattern, captures those lines, opens a new scratch buffer, populates it with the captured lines, sets the syntax highlighting, and then deletes the first line (which typically contains the pattern used for the search).