# Vim Search with "Current Occurrence / Total Occurrences" Shown at the Bottom

Tags: vim, plugins

I am always using `*`/`#` to search for the next/previous occurrence of the variable or function under cursor. Is there a way to display the current occurrence and the total occurrences of my the search result at the bottom of Vim. For example, it could be something like `1 of 5` when you search a word in Chrome.

It doesn't need to list all the occurrences in a window, but I guess it should be able to know all the occurrences in the background.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668623/show-count-of-matches-in-vim

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373293/vim-how-to-store-the-grep-results-in-a-buffer/6374004#6374004

Comment: @FDinoff: Thanks. IndexedSearch is the one that I want. I didn't find the question when I search it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vimgrep` that will open the list in the bottom

```
  :vimgrep foo %
  :copen
```

`:cclose` to close the list.

You can use `:cnext` or `:cprevious` to navigate in the list of results.

`%` is an alias for current file name & path.

You can also use the option `grepprg` and the command `:grep` to use system grep.

As mentioned by sehe, `lgrep` or `lvimgrp` is another possible variable.(with associated `lopen`, `lclose`,...)

Have a look at `:help grep` to see what options are better for you.

Comment: Or use `lvimgrep` with `lopen`. Won't interfere with your regular quickfix cycle

Comment: It is worth noting that this trick does not work w/ scratch buffers because there is no file. I would also mappings for working w/ the quickfix list or location list. I use Tim Pope's unimpaired plugin: https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired