# Display all lines matching a pattern in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I search for a particular string in a file in vim, and I want all the lines with matching string to be displayed, perhaps in another vim window.

Currently I do this:

Search for 'string'

```
/string
```

and move to next matching string

```
n or N
```

Bur, I want all the lines with matching string at one place.

For example:

1 Here is a string

2 Nothing here

3 Here is the same string

I want lines 1 and 3 to be displayed as below, highlighting `string`

1 Here is a **string**

3 Here is the same **string**

Comment: Take a look at [CtrlSF](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
:g/pattern/#<CR>
```

lists all the lines matching `pattern`. You can then do `:23<CR>` to jump to line 23.

```
:ilist pattern<CR>
```

is an alternative that filters out comments and works across includes.

The command below:

```
:vimgrep pattern %|cwindow<CR>
```

will use Vim's built-in grep-like functionality to search for `pattern` in the current file (`%`) and display the results in the quickfix window.

```
:grep pattern %|cwindow<CR>
```

does the same but uses an external program. Note that `:grep` and `:vimgrep` work with *files*, not buffers.

Reference:

```
:help :g
:help include-search
:help :vimgrep
:help :grep
:help :cwindow
```

---

FWIW, my plugin [vim-qlist](https://github.com/romainl/vim-qlist) combines the features of `:ilist` *and* the quickfix window.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments I believe your file looks like this, i.e. the line numbers are not part of the text:

```
Here is a string
Nothing here
Here is the same string
```

You could [copy all lines matching a pattern](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g) into a named register ("a" in the example below), then paste it into a new file:

```
:g/string/y A
:e newfile
:"ap
```

Which gets you:

```
Here is a string
Here is the same string
```

Alternatively, you can use the `grep` command and add `-n` to include line numbers:

```
:grep -n string %
```

```
1:~/tmp.txt [text]                          line: 3 of 3, col: 23 (All)
:!grep -nH -n string /home/christofer/tmp.txt 2>&1| tee /tmp/vHg7GcV/3
[No write since last change]
/home/christofer/tmp.txt:1:Here is a string
/home/christofer/tmp.txt:3:Here is the same string
(1 of 2): Here is a string
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

By default you'll get the output in the "command buffer" down at the bottom (don't know its proper name), but [you can store it in several different places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373293/vim-how-to-store-the-grep-results-in-a-buffer), using `:copen` for example.

Comment: I thought the lines were part of the text. If you are using linux you could call `grep -n` on the buffer which also gives you line numbers. I'll try and get an example of that too.

Comment: I use gVim on windows

Comment: I did some reading and it turns out that the `grep` command is implemented in Vim itself and should be available on Windows too. I initially though of calling `:! grep -n string %`, which uses the OS' `grep` (in my case Ubuntu), but you could just drop the `!` and use Vim's `grep` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Following [this answer over on the Vi StackExchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16460):

`:v/mystring/d`

This will remove all lines not containing *mystring* and will highlight *mystring* in the remaining lines.