# how grep results into separate buffer or split window

Tags: vim

i try to grep current file and then the results to be in separate buffer or split window , NOT in the current buffer im in
i need it to work with simple vim not using quickfix methods (vimgrep and such) 
i did try this :

```
:r!grep foo %
```

[VIM: How to store the grep results in a buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373293/vim-how-to-store-the-grep-results-in-a-buffer)

but it replaces the current buffer and only doing undo returns the previous file content
so my question is:
 how to redirect the results or separate buffer or split window

Answer (score 3):

1. Open a new buffer (here in a vertical window):

   ```
   :vnew
   ```
2. Fill it with the output of a `grep` of the alternate file:

   ```
   :0r!grep foo #
   ```

In one go:

```
:vnew | 0r!grep foo #
```

Comment: Huh, I would have sworn it wouldn't let me put the contents of `grep` into an unnamed buffer.

Comment: Quite.  Sure makes my solution look like the vim equivalent of the ioccc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works perfectly in all scenarios, but give this a shot:

`:execute "vnew" "tmp_buffer_" . winbufnr(winnr()) | execute "0r !grep foo" bufname(winbufnr(winnr()+1))`

The first part should create a new buffer in a vertical split. I gave it a subscript with the buffer number it is associated with to avoid possible clashes with running this on multiple buffers.  The second performs the read operation and figures which buffer to run the grep on by assuming the buffer to be grepped is in the next window over (which I believe should hold true since we've done a fresh split)

Comment: Use `expand()` with the alternative buffer is simpler. e.g. `command! -nargs=+ Bgrep new | pu=system('grep <args> ' . expand('#')) | 0d_`. use like `:Bgrep foo`

Comment: @PeterRincker forgive my yellow-belt level vimfu, but how does the alternate file come into play?  Isn't that for buffers sharing the same window?